# Qt Serial Port + Database

Tags: database, qt, serial-port

Regarding example "enumerator" I have created a project called MySerialPort and I have copied the enumerator main.cpp file to my project MySerialPort sources files. I have left the mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h files untouched and the form as well. When I run my project I get following errors that I don't understand: [see this image for list of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djFsN.jpg)

Comment: Did you add `serialport` to your pro-file (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-enumerator-enumerator-pro.html)? If yes (or after you added it), try to run qmake and check if works.

Comment: Felix thanks. I added serialport to the pro-file and now runs ok. More questions will be coming up... How do I use code formatting in comments?

Comment: Hi! I tried adding a piece of code so that to write to the serial port but got some errors.                                                                                                              1.QSerialPort serialPort;
    2.int serialPortBaudRate = QSerialPort::Baud9600;
   3. serialPort.setBaudRate(serialPortBaudRate);                                                                                  I added the above 3 lines before the return a.exec();

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/yq4mgwe2f/Build_Errors_1_1_16.jpg